# Text to Speech get System default pitch and speech rate

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, saiy

When a user has set a network synthesised voice as their default, my application caches commonly occurring requests to prevent future network latency.

How I do this, is demonstrated in my code [here](https://github.com/brandall76/Saiy-PS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ai/saiy/android/service/helper/SelfAwareCache.java). Briefly, it matches the engine name and utterance to a request and if they match, I stream the cached audio instead of using the TTS Engine.

If a user subsequently alters their pitch and speech rate in the Android Text to Speech Settings, the cached audio will of course no longer reflect this and needs to be ignored and 're-cached', or the audio manipulated accordingly.

**My Question: How do I get the System default Settings, for Pitch and Speech Rate.**

To **set** the Pitch & Rate, exposed methods are available in the [TextToSpeech API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html):

```
/**
 * Sets the speech rate.
 *
 * This has no effect on any pre-recorded speech.
 *
 * @param speechRate Speech rate. {@code 1.0} is the normal speech rate,
 *            lower values slow down the speech ({@code 0.5} is half the normal speech rate),
 *            greater values accelerate it ({@code 2.0} is twice the normal speech rate).
 *
 * @return {@link #ERROR} or {@link #SUCCESS}.
 */
public int setSpeechRate(float speechRate) {
    if (speechRate > 0.0f) {
        int intRate = (int)(speechRate * 100);
        if (intRate > 0) {
            synchronized (mStartLock) {
                mParams.putInt(Engine.KEY_PARAM_RATE, intRate);
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return ERROR;
}

/**
 * Sets the speech pitch for the TextToSpeech engine.
 *
 * This has no effect on any pre-recorded speech.
 *
 * @param pitch Speech pitch. {@code 1.0} is the normal pitch,
 *            lower values lower the tone of the synthesized voice,
 *            greater values increase it.
 *
 * @return {@link #ERROR} or {@link #SUCCESS}.
 */
public int setPitch(float pitch) {
    if (pitch > 0.0f) {
        int intPitch = (int)(pitch * 100);
        if (intPitch > 0) {
            synchronized (mStartLock) {
                mParams.putInt(Engine.KEY_PARAM_PITCH, intPitch);
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return ERROR;
}
```

Given that the above methods both result in placing values into the `Private Bundle` of the bound TTS Engine ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java#680)):

```
private final Bundle mParams = new Bundle();
```

I used reflection to see if these values were defaulted/persisted or injected by the bound engine. Below is a condensed example, where [the Class](https://github.com/brandall76/Saiy-PS/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ai/saiy/android/tts/SaiyTextToSpeech.java) extends `TextToSpeech`:

```
private int getSpeechRate() {

    Bundle reflectBundle;

    try {

        final Field f = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(TTSDefaults.BOUND_PARAMS);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        reflectBundle = (Bundle) f.get(this);

        if (reflectBundle != null && !reflectBundle.isEmpty()) {
                examineBundle(reflectBundle);

            if (reflectBundle.containsKey(TTSDefaults.KEY_PARAM_RATE)) {

                final int reflectRate = reflectBundle.getInt(TTSDefaults.KEY_PARAM_RATE);

                // log

                return reflectRate;

            } else {
                // missing
            }

        } else {
            // empty or null
        }

    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
    }

    return -1;
}

/**
 * For debugging the bundle extras
 *
 * @param bundle containing potential extras
 */
private void examineBundle(@Nullable final Bundle bundle) {

    if (bundle != null) {
        final Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        //noinspection Convert2streamapi
        for (final String key : keys) {
            Log.v(CLS_NAME, "examineBundle: " + key + " ~ " + bundle.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

The values are missing and therefore, perhaps understandably, this is not how they are 'globally' persisted.

When I first attempted to resolve this issue, I assumed it would be trivial - I hope that proves to be the case, but I just can't see the wood for the trees...

Thanks for reading this far - help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I assumed you are familiar with TextToSpeech source code.

I don't think you will be able to get the pitch and speech rate by using reflection. Those values are stored in an instance variable in TextToSpeech class and they are given to the engine every time when you query a text. Meaning that when you call `setSpeechRate` or `setPitch` methods they do not alter the pitch and speech rate for the global Text to Speech Settings.

In addition to this, [pitch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#TTS_DEFAULT_PITCH) and [speech rate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#TTS_DEFAULT_RATE) are defined in Android secure system settings which are the preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs (system apps or root access) for those values, not modified directly by applications.

Read the secure settings related to pitch and speech rate with below codes:

```
Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.TTS_DEFAULT_RATE);
Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.TTS_DEFAULT_PITCH);
```

Slightly different usages can be seen in [Google Talkback](https://github.com/google/talkback/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/utils/FailoverTextToSpeech.java#L551) and [TextToSpeechSettings](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/b7e46e89d77574dbb51855144ea3d46fcf220bbb/src/com/android/settings/TextToSpeechSettings.java#164).

Surround with `Settings.SettingNotFoundException` which will be thrown if no value has been set, in which case you can fall back to the equivalent values of [the hidden](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java#247) `TextToSpeech.Engine.FALLBACK_TTS_DEFAULT_PITCH`

Alternatively, you can add an extra parameter in as the default value.

```
Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.TTS_DEFAULT_PITCH, FALLBACK_TTS_DEFAULT_PITCH);
```

Comment: Thank you - I searched the damn secure settings, but somehow did not find the ones you reference... They are returning values for me, but they won't unless a user actually alters them in the TextToSpeech Settings (or an app directly alters the Secure Setting). Perhaps that is why you weren't getting values in your tests? I'm going to edit your answer a little, so it's more concise for future readers. Let me know you're happy with the edits and I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: You are right, I didn't alter them. Your edit looks good to me except it does not mention the null case. What do you do if you get null, assume TextToSpeech.Engine.FALLBACK_TTS_DEFAULT_PITCH?

Comment: Ah, I need to edit again. It should be `getInt()`. If there is no default value, the exception will be thrown. I'll also add the alternative default value option.

Answer (score 2):

It says in the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech)

> Speech rate. 1.0 is the normal speech rate, lower values slow down the speech (0.5 is half the normal speech rate), greater values accelerate it (2.0 is twice the normal speech rate).
>
> Speech pitch. 1.0 is the normal pitch, lower values lower the tone of the synthesized voice, greater values increase it.

So, `setPitch((float) 1.0)` and `setSpeechRate((float) 1.0)` sets the default pitch and speech rate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to set pitch from the device settings to your TextToSpeech:

```
float pitch = Settings.Secure.getFloat(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.TTS_DEFAULT_PITCH);
textToSpeech.setPitch((float) (pitch / 100.0));
```